# Having my chocolate coins and eating them too

Tags: food

I love chocolate "coins" - that is, foil covered chocolates in the shape of coins.  Unfortunately I both like to look at the coins as well as eat the chocolate.  My problem is, once I open the foil to eat the chocolate, I am not longer able to hold the "coin" in my hand and despite my efforts to carefully open the foil and then put it back together I rarely succeed in anything that looks near as good as the original.

I know this may seem silly, but I am looking for some hack that will allow me to extract the chocolate without losing the shape of the coin, to give the appearance that the foil still contains something inside it.  Better yet if I could somehow inject something back into the foil that would harden and retain the original feel.

Yes, I could just never open the coins, but then all the chocolate could go to waste.  I could also just buy real gold coins, but I don't have the money.

Comment: Chocolate is cheap, and about the same price as whatever you'd replace it with (wax, epoxy) -> buy the coins, buy a chocolate bar, eat the chocolate bar, don't eat the chocolate inside the coin. It's not a waste, because you're going to spend as much again faking the chocolate back for a worse result than you achieve by just not eating the coin

Comment: Especially as the chocolate in coins is cheap yucky stuff anyway...

Answer (score 3):

What you can do if you want to save the foil and make it look as if there was still something inside:
Try to remove the foil from the chocolate carefully, then lay both halves of the foil out in front of you. Light a candle and let some of the wax drip on to the foil until it is enough to glue the foil together- plus it looks as if there is still chocolate inside. The foil/coin goes back to its original shape once you put the two halves together and let the wax harden.

Answer (score 2):

You could just cut out the chocolate coin stage completely. You can buy a "chocolate Coin Making Centre". Here is the link on Amazon:

https://www.amazon.co.uk/Golden-Coin-Maker-John-Adams-x/dp/B00083D79U/

You can make the gold foil and fill it with the substance of your choice - thus negating the need to carefully unwrap the chocolate at all.

I think @Julia's suggestion of using candle wax would be a good facsimile of chocolate - but epoxy would be good too.

Comment: That's an intriguing product... although the fact that it has more 1 star ratings than 5 star ratings is concerning.

Comment: My children had one about 10 years ago, that was how I knew about it. As I remember, the device for pressing the gold foil worked very well. Melting the chocolate and putting it into the foil moulds was messy and too difficult.

Comment: I wonder if it would work better (or at all!) with something like wax...